# Get multiple database queries from php to ajax success response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to pass two variables to my ajax success response so that i can use them in a some html to display on the page. As you can see i've tried passing them as an array but it ends up empty. How do i pass both php variables and access them in my ajax success call?

```
//show datpicker calendar set function on select
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    onSelect: getDate
});

function getDate(response){
    var selectedDate = $('#datepicker').val();
    var values = {'selectedDate': selectedDate };

    $.ajax({
        url: '/reservations/admin/dateRequest',
        type: 'POST',
        data: values,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {

          .....use response data here....

        } //end success
    });//end ajax call

    return false;
}
```

My PHP

```
public function differentDate() {
    //get selected date from datepicker selection   
    $selectedDate = $_POST['selectedDate'];
    //convert the selected date to carbon element
    $ConvertedSelectedDate =  new Carbon($selectedDate);
    //find day of week based on selection/conversion
    $dayOfWeek = $ConvertedSelectedDate->dayOfWeek;

    $times = ReservationTimeSlot::where('day_of_week', '=', $dayOfWeek)->get();
    $parties = Party::where('date', '=', $ConvertedSelectedDate)->get();

    $response = ['times' => $times, 'parties' => $parties];

    return $response;
}
```

all of this gives me empty arrays

```
 {"times":{},"parties":{}}
```

Comment: Don't use `$_POST['selectedDate']`, use `request('selectedDate')`, or even `request()->input('selectedDate')`

Comment: What do you get with `console.log(values);`, you have what you want? And in your php, do you call your function? Where do you do `differentDate()` ? I think you should do `public function differentDate($selecdtDate) { your code }` then in the php where you send you Ajax data do `differentDate($_POST['selectedDate])` then at the end `return json_encode($response)` since your ajax response must be in JSON

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$.ajax({
 url: '/reservations/admin/dateRequest',
 type: 'POST',
 data: {
    'selectedDate': selectedDate,
    'otherVariable' : 1
 }
 dataType: 'json'
}).success(function(response){
   console.log(response.times);
   console.log(response.parties);
});
```

Since you did tag laravel, you can handle the request in your controller like this.,

```
// Make sure you have this line in the begining of the file 
// use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
public function differentDate() {


 $selectedDate = Input::get('selectedDate'); // No need to access $_POST
 $ConvertedSelectedDate =  new Carbon($selectedDate);
 $dayOfWeek = $ConvertedSelectedDate->dayOfWeek;

 $times = ReservationTimeSlot::where('day_of_week', '=', $dayOfWeek)->get();
 $parties = Party::where('date', '=', $ConvertedSelectedDate)->get();



return response()->json([
   'times' => $times,
   'parties' => $parties
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm using laravel 4.2(legacy applicaiton) does the request namespace work in 4.2?

Comment: I belive in laravel 4.2, you use the Input facade, lemme update my answer

Comment: getting this error. Argument 1 passed to ReservationsAdminController::differentDate() must be an instance of Request, none given

Comment: Forgot to remove (Request $request) from function declaration, check again please

Comment: hmm. still getting empty. {"times":{},"parties":{}}. Also im using this in laravel 4 response  return Response::json(array('times' => $times, 'parties' => $parties));

Comment: Are you positive your queries do return objects?